# Why does taking large input from stdin using getline truncate my input?

Tags: c++, string, input, console, getline

I have been trying to take a input from standard input in cpp.

My input contains 1000 numbers (max size of each number <= 10^9) . The problem is when I copy/paste the numbers from a source to my terminal, not all of the numbers get listed on the terminal, and because of that my code gives wrong output.

Here is the screen shot of my terminal:

[image]

I am taking input from `getline()` and storing in a string buffer.

Why is my command prompt truncating my input?

Comment: What os and terminal do you use?

Comment: Add a [minimal reproducilble example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is also recommended.

Comment: @anastaciu are you expecting OP to post 1000 number with up to 10 digits?

Comment: @ThomasSablik no, they are probably expecting that OP will include the necessary details in order to reproduce the problem, i.e., the terminal, the enviroment and sample data that reproduces the problem. You don't have to paste "*1000 numbers up to 10 digits*". You may just specify that "*the problem occurrs when you paste 1000 numbers up to 10 digits*".

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your terminal. Put the input in a file and use redirection; `program < input.txt`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik,do you not know what a minimal reproducilble example is? Can you tell if the problem is in the code or not?

Comment: Maybe unrelated but I don't understand why you would need to insert that much data to the stdin. Could you not just read from file and avoid the issue?

Comment: Re: "my input contains 1000 numbers" -- no, it contains **text** that your program will interpret as numbers. It's not the number of numbers, but the size of the text that matters.

Comment: i need to take input from standard input and hence using cin . Also is there a limit to number of characters which getline is limited to?

Answer (score 3):

From the screenshot it looks like you're using a Windows command prompt. These have a [line limit of 8191](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation):

> In Command Prompt, the total length of the following command line that you use at the command prompt cannot contain more than either 2047 or 8191 characters (as appropriate to your operating system):

If you need to input a large list of number that go beyond that limit, reading them from a file may work better.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can use the tick to accept it - although the advice is to wait for a while to see if you get other, better, answers